# Use another service to log in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web, webforms

i have web form application in asp.net (visual studio v 2015),and i use provider class file (My provider), and create a local web config , and adding the code in main web.config like blow , for redirect users without login to "login page", but when i run the project , application show the default visual studio login page (not my login page) , like attached file , help please .

> Error :
>
> Use another service to log in. There are no external authentication
>   services configured. See this article for details on setting up this
>   ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.

my provider (cs file)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public class MyProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        Models.DB_NewsEntities db1 = new Models.DB_NewsEntities();
        public override string ApplicationName
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetAllRoles()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            int userID = int.Parse(username);

            var result = (from u in db1.Tbl_User join r in db1.Tbl_Role on u.RoleId equals r.RoleID where u.UserId == userID select r.RoleName).ToArray();

            return result;

        }

        public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

main web.confige added code :

```
 <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="none"/>


<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="WebApplication3"  defaultUrl="/AdminPanel/WebForm1.aspx" loginUrl="/Login.aspx" />

    </authentication>

    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyProvider" >

       <providers>
          <clear/>
          <add name="MyProvider" type="WebApplication3.MyProvider"/>
       </providers>

    </roleManager>
```

local web.config :

```
<pre lang="XML"><authorization>

  <allow roles="Admin"/>
  <deny users="*"/>

</authorization>
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyMEp.png)